# restart console on Minecraft Server

Tags: java, terminal, minecraft

Please excuse me for my inexperience, I am very new to this.
I set up a server on Digital Ocean for Minecraft earlier today. I ran the command to create the world with java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.1.15.2.jar nogui, and created a screen.
It gave me access to the console where I could type like /op  and other commands. Later on, I shut down, and now when I try to rejoin, I'm not sure how to get back to that console. I have more than 1 person on the server, who is on the console right now - I don't know if that should cause it any issue. When I retry to open the console with the command java -jar minecraft_server.jar It says there is already a server running (which there is) but I just want to get back to the console.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Im assuming Digital Ocean is a hosting service. Sounds like you need to poke around your hosting service to figure out how to reopen the console. I doubt many people on here are experienced enough using a hosting site for a minecraft server that they can tell you your answer. Try calling a support member for the hosting service.

Comment: @JakeTheSnake Yes Digital Ocean is a hosting service, and I'm sure it's not on their end, I can open up a console to the server, but the way the Minecraft Server works, there's like a console that shows up when you start the server, allowing you to run commands. I just need to know how to get back to that.

Comment: Can you not just resume the screen session you created when you started the screen with the server on?

Answer (score 2):

If this is a linux vserver or root server, you can use the "screen" tool to access the minecraft console again.

1. Create a new startup script (start.sh) in the server directory to launch the JAR:

   ```
    #!/bin/sh

   screen -d -m -S "minecraft_screen" java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.1.15.2.jar nogui
   ```
2. Open your terminal and execute the following in the directory:

   ```
   chmod +x start.sh
   ```
3. Run your start up script:

   ```
   ./start.sh
   ```

To access the minecraft screen use the command "screen -r".

To leave the minecraft screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

As a player logged into the server, stop the server by typing /stop. This will stop and close the server. Now proceed back to your hosting service and start the console the same way you did the first time. If it worked this way the first time, i can imagine itll work the second time.

Comment: The problem is that there are people playing in the server, and doing this kicks them.. I need a way to do it without the server restarting

Comment: Do it when they get off

Answer (score 0):

just noting in case this becomes a resource for other new server owners, as of writing this comment - screen has been depreciated and tmux is it's replacement

- use '**tmux**' to create a screen
- use '**ctrl**+**b**' then '**d**' to detach
- use '**tmux attach**' to rejoin a screen

i spent a little while searching the internet for this, so i thought sharing it here would be logical - apologies if this question is too outdated to still be relevant